# Limiting Wildfly 14 Two-Way SSL to specific clients

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly, mutual-authentication, elytron

We're maintaining a Java application with a JAX-WS SOAP API for external systems running on WildFly 14 application server. The external systems currently connect using common one-way SSL. Our goal is to switch communication to mutual authentication, so two-way SSL.
Not all of the external systems can make the switch at the same time though, so simply enforcing two-way SSL is not an option. We need to migrate them step-by-step during a transition phase. That why I've been wondering: **Is there a possibility to enable two-way SSL on a WildFly HTTPS interface for specific caller IPs only?**

I have based my tests on the [official documentation on setting up regular two-way SSL](http://docs.wildfly.org/14/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#enable-two-way-ssltls-in-wildfly-for-applications). Following these steps, every caller needs to provide a client certificate. Modifying that example configuration to use `want-client-auth` instead of `need-client-auth` softens the checks to support two-way SSL but not require it. Unfortunately that is not enough in our case, because it does not imply guarantees about whether a particular external system is consistently using two-way SSL or not. A system could send some of its requests providing a client certificate, and some without. In other words, business requires a way to say "From this day on, external system *Foo* may only use the API with a client certificate. All the other external systems are unaffected, for now."

To implement this - preferably without application code changes -
I've been reading the documentation of the [new WildFly security module Elytron](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/WildFly+Elytron+Security). It seems quite extensible, but details on custom components are sparse and I haven't found an extension point that sounds like it would help in my case.

The only solution approach I have right now is configuring a separate set of socket-binding and https-listener for Wildfly, similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948388/wildfly-11-elytron-one-way-ssl-and-two-way-ssl-simultaneously). That means we would have two HTTPS ports: One with one-way SSL, and another one with mandatory two-way SSL. As external systems are completing their migration steps, they switch the port used for invoking our API. Forcing them to only use the two-way SSL port from then on would require specific firewall rules, but should be possible.

So, this solution is rather simple in technical implementation but leads to overhead for re-configuring the external systems and adapting firewall rules. That's why I'd be happy about any suggestions for a solution that is more elegant, or hints how to use Elytron for that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you came to best conclusion. Elytron does not have possibility to choose SSL Context based on client parameters (What would that be? Client IP address? That can change when behind the load balancer.)

So I think only way is to have different SSLContext configured on different ports (or hostnames).

Regarding extending server. I guess SSL handshake is very early step and after that different customisation points take part. I thought about some Undertow custom handler, something similar to [1], but as I said that would be too late.

[1] http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/index.html#redirect-handler

Comment: Thanks for confirming that - and you're right, even a solution based on client IPs would be problematic when behind a proxy or load balancer. 
I'll give the question a bit more time before accepting your answer as final, though. :-)